# Should we rename the following android version tags?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

Most version tags of android are in the format **[android-versionNumber-fullVersionName]**  example `[android-8.0-oreo]` `[android-7.0-nougat]` . It will be good if we follow same pattern for all android version tags .

Also I think in beta stages **[android-versionNumber]** would be right because it will take months for official release of name but after officially release it should be renamed to **[android-versionNumber-fullVersionName]**  .

Proposed tags to rename are

[android-9.0-p](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-9.0-p) to [android-9.0-pie](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-9.0-pie)

[android-6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0.1) to [android-6.0.1-marshmallow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-6.0.1-marshmallow)

[android-4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.0) to [android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich)

[android4.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android4.0.3) to [android-4.0.3-ice-cream-sandwich](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-4.0.3-ice-cream-sandwich)

[android-3.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.1) to [android-3.1-honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.1-honeycomb)

[android-3.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.2) to [android-3.2-honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-3.2-honeycomb)

Comment: I believe it's a good idea, it makes the tags more consistent, and it helps to keep track of the version names.

Comment: If we're going to do it this way, it will require mod involvement for every major android release, since initially the full name is not known and the community can't rename tags by themselves. I'm not sure that's a good idea.

Comment: [android-6.0.1] probably can be made a synonym of [android-6.0-marshmallow]. Not sure why we need [android-6.0.1-marshmallow]..

Comment: What if someone is experiencing a problem that only happens on that specific version? Should the tag be more generic (e.g only `6.0`), or more specific (e.g. `6.0.1`)? This is Android after all, we're full of fringe cases.

Comment: @Mauker such cases are bugs, and bugs tend to stick.

Comment: Why have the code name at all? The information is useless.

Comment: @Floern and -4.0 and -4.03?

Comment: @rene 4.0 and 4.0.3 have different API levels (i.e. are different SDK versions), while 6.0 and 6.0.1 don't.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense @Floern. I wasn't sure if it was an oversight .